# Facebook not giving meta preview for new Wordpress posts

Tags: facebook, wordpress, meta-tags

I have had issues with Facebook not showing preview image before, but now Facebook doesn't suggest preview at all on our new Wordpress posts, the oldest one being one month old. **And there seems to no difference on those posts OG metadata than with those older posts that does get preview correctly.**

This month old post doesn't get preview at all: http://markokaarto.fi/kuinka-sijoitan-asuntoihin/

This one gets:http://markokaarto.fi/vmaiset-remonttimiehet/

Comment: Your meta tags are not in the page head, they're at the end of the `body`

Answer (score 0):

Try using a URl shortner are you posting on a specific page or a facebook group please specify, also keep the text discription of the post limited to 90 characters.